# C : Arduino : Check to see if all the values in an array are larger than x and set them to zero

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

What I'm trying to do is: if any of the values stored in the elements of the  array are larger than 2, set the value of that element in the array to zero

```
int  column[] = { 0-var1, 1-var3, 2-var2, 3-var6, 4-var7 };

if (column[] > 2){
    column[] = 0;
}
```

but obviously it can't run the code because I didn't specify which index but this is the point I don't want it to check one element only, I want it to check the whole array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your questions correctly then you need to loop over the array to check each element:

```
int column[] = {0-var1,1-var3,2-var2,3-var6,4-var7};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (column[i] > 2) column[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the if statement inside a loop with an index.

```
for(x=0; x < sizeof(column) / sizeof(int); x++) {
  if (column[x] > 2) {
      column[x] = 0;
  }
}
```